# TortoiseSVN: How to completely remove all the information of a project (working copy) from the repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I was using TortoiseSVN for backing up some very **large binary files**, which I no longer need. I want to **recover** back this **disk space** from the repository. All these files/folders were maintained under a single project (working copy) in TortoiseSVN under a single directory.

How do I delete **all** the versioned files and information related to this project from the SVN **Repository**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this from SVN itself.  You basically have to [dump and rebuild](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) the whole repository to do this.  There is no `svn destroy` command, per se.  That is by design.  It keeps your history intact pretty much no matter what.

This guy seems to be pretty mad about it, but I personally think that a user-accessible `svn destroy` or `svn obliterate` or whatever is pretty much an anti-feature of a SCC system!

http://blog.projectnibble.org/2008/03/01/subversion-obliterate-the-forgotten-feature/

Comment: +1 I've successfully shrunk a repo with some reckless commits using history filtering.

Comment: An obilterate feature would be very useful if you needed to remove sensitive information or large files that were accidently added.  But, yeah, other than that I cannot think of many use cases where it would be appropriate.

Comment: @Brian:  That's true, that is a totally legit use.  And I choose to ignore it as a possibility until I get bit with this problem (oh, and with my luck, it'll be next week or so...)

Comment: Brian: But the reasons you mention are pretty compelling by themselves! I am surprised to realize that I cannot obliterate from SVN! :-(

Comment: @Ashwin: You can (dump and rebuild), but it isn't easy. And that's by design. You don't want anyone to just remove something from your repository in a way that it will never be recoverable. In order to do so you need access to the server, admin rights, and probably a bit experience. I actually consider this a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could imagine an environment where a programmer wants to obliterate commits to cover up his responsibility for a mistake. Or perhaps a more commmon problem would be, a novice programmer obliterates something he shouldn't have through ignorance and now all history is lost, or even a competent experienced programmer makes a mistake. Those scenarios are good reasons to make obliteration hard or require special privileges.

But I've had a number of times when we've decided to restructure our repositories for one reason or another. If, say, we have one repository on server A and another on server B, and we decide to move a project from A to B, I would really like to obliterate it from A. Otherwise, six months from now someone might find the copy on A and not realize it is no longer current.

Especially when I was first learning SVN, I made a lot of bad decisions about how to organize branches and tags that I later wanted to rework. I really wanted to just obliterate the old structure and put it all back right. Again, to avoid confusing anyone who looks at the history.

Comment: if that's the concern, providing a list of users who are permitted to use the destructive command will do.